# Undefined property, even though it's there

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an object, `Brand`, and I want to print the `id` of this object.

I am getting the following error when doing `return Sentry::getUser()->brand()->get()->id`:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id
```

However, if I remove the `->id` part, I am getting the whole object just fine, including the `id` (`return Sentry::getUser()->brand()->get()`)

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can't you cut/paste that data dump rather than using an image?

Comment: `->get(['id']);` Might be what you're after, or use `first()->id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
return Sentry::getUser()->brand()->first()->id;
```

Otherwise, you end up with a collection of users (even though that collection may only contain one user).

Answer (score 0):

it might be reserved in a framework you used. My guess s that every object of any kind is a default object-type object that has an id of its own. If possible change the "id" to brand_id or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one object and will always be one, you can use return Sentry::getUser()->brand()->first()->id. That retrieves a single object, while get () returns an array of objects even if there is only one match.